# Study resource for Digital communication

Tags: digital-communications, reference-request, books

I am in my 5th semester of computer science and we have a digital communication course. All the textbooks of digital comm. available in my library demand a prerequisite of Circuit analysis and Signals and systems.
Is there any book which is self contained or at least less heavy on these background topics?

Comment: Digital communications necessarily depends on signals. Without understanding of signal theory, you really stand no chance to understand what is happening in digital communication. There might be more-or-less self-contained books, but I don't think it'll be worth the hassle. Ask the professor what kind of signal theory book he'd recommend as basis for a CS student, and read that.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you the book *Schaum's outlines of Analog and Digital Communications*.

It will be the fastest refresher for the signal processing and probability concepts which are essential prerequisites for digital communications. It's not using that heavy math also, nevertheless, not a trivial one either ;-)

Comment: I always recommend that book -- for the price you can get it used, it's a no brainer.

Comment: Yes. Before any serious study of communications, the subjects in this book shall be mastered well. Then the more *brainer* ones can be tried :-) Definitely useful.